# Removing require and define using amdclean

Tags: requirejs

I am trying to remove require and define calls using amdclean so that I can call my js file, without calling requirejs. Also, I would be able to run closure compiler on the js project.

My js file compiles fine with the requirejs grunt configuration:

```
requirejs:
      build:
        options:
          mainConfigFile : "client/main.js"
          baseUrl : "client"
          name: "main"
          out: "build/main.js"
          removeCombined: true
          findNestedDependencies: true
```

However, when I add the amdclean to it, it does not actually take out the require and define calls from the code. Here's the config:

```
requirejs:
      build:
        options:
          mainConfigFile : "client/main.js"
          baseUrl : "client"
          name: "main"
          out: "build/main.js"
          removeCombined: true
          findNestedDependencies: true
          onModuleBundleComplete: (data) ->
            fs = module.require('fs')
            amdclean = module.require('amdclean')
            #console.log('data.path = ' + data.path)
            inputFile = data.path
            outputFile = './build/clean.js'
            cleanedCode = amdclean.clean(
              'filePath': inputFile
            )
            fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, cleanedCode)
```

Here's the amdclean url:

http://gregfranko.com/amdclean/

I can still use the amdclean output if I use it with requirejs, but not as an independant script. Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use AMDclean without some sort of dependency ordering logic (which the Require.js optimizer provides).  You don't necessarily have to use the Require.js optimizer, but you need to replace it with some library that provides similar functionality.